# Using a CTE in OVER(PARTITION BY)

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression, window-functions

I'm trying to calculate volume from 3 columns in a table and return only unique volumes. We have many rows with the same `Width`, `Height`, and `Length` and so naturally my volume calculation will have duplicate return values for `Volume`. I am under the impression that, in order to accomplish this, I must use `OVER`, `PARTITION` and a `CTE` as aliases are not allowed to be referenced in `OVER`

```
WITH
cteVolume (Id, Volume)
AS 
(
    SELECT Id, Width * Height * [Length] AS Volume FROM  PackageMaterialDimensions
)
SELECT * 
INTO #volumeTempTable
FROM (
SELECT pp.ID, (pp.Width * pp.Height * pp.[Length]) AS Volume,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY cte.Volume ORDER BY pp.ID DESC) rn
FROM PlanPricing pp
INNER JOIN cteVolume cte ON pp.ID = cte.Id
) a
WHERE rn = 1

SELECT * FROM #volumeTempTable
ORDER BY Volume DESC

DROP TABLE #volumeTempTable
```

*Note, the reason for the temp tables is because I plan on doing some extra work with this data. I also am currently debugging so I am using these tables to output to the data window*

**Here is what is wrong with this query**
- It is still returning duplicates
- It is only returning one volume for every row
- It is only returning about 75 rows when there are 71000 rows in the table

**How can I modify this query to essentially do the following**
- Calculate volume for EVERY row in the table
- SELECT rows with unique volume calculations. (I do not want to see the same volume twice in my result set)

*Edit - providing data as requested*

**Current data set**  Ignore the extra columns
[image]

**What I would like is**
ID  |  Volume
193 |  280
286 |  350
274 |  550
241 |  720

Basically, I want to calculate volume for every row, then I would like to somehow group by volume in order to cut down duplicates and select the first row from each group

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "SELECT rows DISTINCT by volume".  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: @Adrian Is `SELECT MIN(id), Width * Height * [Length] AS Volume FROM PackageMaterialDimensions GROUP BY Width * Height * [Length]` insufficient?

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you want?

```
WITH cteVolume (Id, Volume) AS (
      SELECT Id, Width * Height * [Length] AS Volume
      FROM PackageMaterialDimensions
    )
SELECT DISTINCT volume
FROM CTE ;
```

If you want one id per volume:

```
WITH cteVolume (Id, Volume) AS (
      SELECT Id, Width * Height * [Length] AS Volume
      FROM PackageMaterialDimensions
    )
SELECT volume, MIN(Id) as Id
FROM CTE
GROUP BY volume;
```

Comment: No, because I have duplicate volumes in the result set. I just updated the question with the info you asked for. Let me know if that info clarifies things.

Comment: I can do a `DISTINCT` in the query you suggested but the problem now becomes that I need more data than just the volume. I need Ids at the very minimum

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see you can't use windows functions inside the recursive part of the CTE. You have to sum them manually, inside the CTE part.
So, instead of

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY cte.Volume ORDER BY pp.ID DESC) rn
```

Just write

```
1 as rn
```

in the first part, and

```
rn+1 as rn
```

in the second part.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your issue is coming from partitioning `cte.volume` from the `PackageMaterialDimensions` table, but you're also selecting `pp.volume` from the `PlanPricing` table?

Not able to confirm without more information on your data set and tables.